# Google Sheets SUMPRODUCT and IFS on different sheets

Tags: worksheet-function, google-sheets

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMPRODUCT((Products!B2:B=D2)*(IFS(H2="x",Products!D2:D,I2="x",Products!E2:E,J2="x",Products!F2:F)*(E2:E))))
```

I have a spreadsheet with an Orders sheet and a Products sheet. Product names (from B2:B) are data validated on the Orders sheet (D2:D) and also have adjacent cells with the quantity (E2:E) and 3 columns indicating what discount was given by use of an "x" (Consultant [H2:H], Preferred [I2:I], Retail [J2:J]). There are up to 3 prices per product (on Products sheet) reflective of the discount columns on the Orders sheet. I am trying to do the following:

**Match** *ordered product* `(Orders!Product(D2:D))` **with** *product name* `(Products!Product(B2:B))` **multiply** *quantity* `(Orders!Qty(E2:E))` **by** *price* `(Products!'Consultant Price'(D2:D), Products!'Preferred Price'(E2:E), Products!'Retail Price'(F2:F))` **if** *discount* `(Orders!Consultant(H2:H), Orders!Preferred(I2:I), Orders!Retail(J2:J))` **equals** `x`

What functions or arrays should I be using differently.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IFERROR(PRODUCT(IFS(H2="x",VLOOKUP(D2,Products!$B$2:$I$100,3,0),I2="x",VLOOKUP(D2,Products!$B$2:$I$100,4,0),J2="x",VLOOKUP(D2,Products!$B$2:$I$100,5,0)),E2),"")
```

was able to achieve this with a little assistance from a friend

Answer (score 0):

In [your solution](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/139275) you are repeating the VLOOKUP unnecessarily:

> ```
> =IFERROR(PRODUCT(
>    IFS(H2="x", VLOOKUP(D2,Products!$B$2:$I$100, 3, 0),
>        I2="x", VLOOKUP(D2,Products!$B$2:$I$100, 4, 0),
>        J2="x", VLOOKUP(D2,Products!$B$2:$I$100, 5, 0)), E2), "")
> ```

Since it is only the VLOOKUP's index that varies, you can include a single VLOOKUP and use the IFS function for that argument:

```
=IFERROR(PRODUCT(
   VLOOKUP(D2, Products!$B$2:$I$100,
           IFS(H2="x",3, I2="x",4, J2="x",5), 0), E2), "")
```

## Other Code Reductions

- The PRODUCT function can be replaced with the multiplication sign **`*`**
- Sheets doesn't require specifying an empty string **`""`** in IFERROR. 
  eg. **`IFERROR(value)`** is acceptable, no need for **`IFERROR(value, "")`**
- If IFERROR is being used to handle VLOOKUP errors when no **`"x"`** is found, it can be replaced by IFNA as those errors will be **`#N/A`**.
- You could use the LOOKUP function rather than IFS which will avoid repeating the search string and allow you to use the range **`H2:J2`** rather than one-off cells.

```
=IFNA(VLOOKUP(
   D2, Products!$B$2:$I$100,
   LOOKUP("x", H2:J2, {3,4,5}))*E2)
```